# Ruby. Slow hash value look up with large hash's

Tags: ruby

I'm working with a hash size of 10 million...

```
hash={'Aatater'=>2, 'Bbabber'=>3, 'Xaazerx'=>2, 'Caackersc'=>1}
```

searching for a Key is impressively quick. even if the key exist at the end of a hash...

```
hash['Caackersc']=>1
```

but if you search for a value that exist deep in the hash it will be painfully slow.

```
hash.key(1)=>"Caackersc"
```

So. My first attempt to achieve great speeds when searching for a value. I thought I would invert the hash. But this would cause duplicate values to be removed.

```
hash.invert{ 2=>'Xaazerx', 3=>'Bbabber', 1=>'Caackersc'}
```

So I then tried to invert the hash myself with out loosing data... by issuing a index number befor every new key.

```
I_hash=Hash.new

hash.to_a.each_with_index{|h,i| i_hash[[i.to_s,h[1].to_s]]=h[0]}

{["0","2"]=>'Aatater', ["1","3"]=>'Bbabber', ["2","2"]=>' Xaazerx', ["3","1"]=>'Caackersc'}
```

So. At this point I can search for the new key with the same wicked quick speeds.

```
i_hash[["1","3"]] => "Bbabber"
```

But now... I hope the index part of the key could be found with a regex?

```
I_hash[/\d/,"3"]=>fail, nil
```

so... this was my best attempt to speed up a value search but it will only work in my situation if I can regex the first array of the key.

Comment: Why are you dealing with a Hash of size ten million at all? Why aren't you using a database?

Comment: If OP doesn't need long-term persistence, and it meets their performance needs, I don't think it's crazy to use a hash.

Comment: I have tried dbm. I believe searching for keys was a little to slow for this application... I may need to retest though... I have not exceeded ram so its not necessary

Answer (score 4):

You've got the right idea. For your inverted hash you want each value to be an array of the corresponding keys in the original hash. Something like this:

```
hash = { 'Aatater' => 2, 'Bbabber' => 3, 'Xaazerx' => 2, 'Caackersc' => 1 }

inv_hash = hash.keys.group_by {|k| hash[k] }

p inv_hash
# => { 2 => [ "Aatater", "Xaazerx" ],
#      3 => [ "Bbabber" ],
#      1 => [ "Caackersc" ] }

p inv_hash[2]
# => [ "Aatater", "Xaazerx" ]
```

Comment: `inv_hash = hash.keys.group_by{|k| hash[k] }`

Answer (score 1):

You could also compute the inverse like this:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }
  #=> {2=>["Aatater", "Xaazerx"], 3=>["Bbabber"], 1=>["Caackersc"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hit performance problem, you could consider using [redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: redis was a suggestion that I have followed, I  installed a cluster of servers With a example tutorial found online... but I don't see anyway to search the database for a value. redis is only supporting key searching?

Comment: Accessing the data from the keys is order of magnitude faster, that's for sure. You could have two databases, one for the normal hash and one for the inverted one. Otherwise a SQL database should do the job